# How to handle fragment load again and again

Tags: android

In my app, I have navigation bottom and container above navigation. I using multiple fragments in one container. When I click on an item of navigation bottom, I replace the fragment to show.

This is my code that shows fragment in the container

```
private void showFragment(String tabType) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    baseTabBottomFragment = new BaseTabBottomFragment();
    //send data to fragment
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(KeyConstant.TAB_BOTTOM, tabType);
    baseTabBottomFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    ft.add(R.id.frame_container, baseTabBottomFragment, tabType);
    ft.addToBackStack(tabType);
    ft.commit();
}
```

But I don't know, how to handle when I click on the item navigation bottom, It's always loaded fragment again and again. I want to handle it. If fragment loaded, I don't want to load it again.

Please help me

Sorry for English grammar

Answer (score 1):

1-You can play with that tag `tabType` e.g:

```
String prevTab = "";
private void showFragment(String tabType) {
    if(!tabType.equal(prevTab)){
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    baseTabBottomFragment = new BaseTabBottomFragment();
    //send data to fragment
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(KeyConstant.TAB_BOTTOM, tabType);
    baseTabBottomFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    ft.add(R.id.frame_container, baseTabBottomFragment, tabType);
    ft.addToBackStack(tabType);
    ft.commit();
   }
  prevTab = tabType;
}
```

2-Or from your `BottomNavigationView` you can check for selected item id, e.g:

`if (bottomNav.getSelectedItemId() != R.id.someMenuId)`
    // replace the fragment

3- Or use [`onNavigationItemReselcted`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener) add from Api 26 to know if the current item got selected again or not.